# vim buffer switch is not working

Tags: vim, buffer

I used to open multiples files in vi using the following command:

`vi file*`

After that in command mode `:b2`,`:b3`,`:b4`  used to switch between files. But now it is not working.
 Any clues?

Comment: When you do `:ls`, is any of the buffers marked with `#`?

Comment: @romainl, no in any case, the command mode doesn't disappear, only the cursor goes to the top of same file. However :q, :w etc are working, and quitting vi showing "2 files to edit".

Answer (score 0):

The `:b#` is made to switch to the *alternate* buffer, that is, the last buffer you opened before the current one. So if you just started a session, there is no alternate buffer, and this special buffer name can't be set to anything.

First run at least one command to open another buffer, like `:n`, then `:b#` will start to do its job.

Comment: `<c-^>` / `<c-6>` is the same as `:b #`

Comment: oh I am sorry. I didn't know `b#` is itself a command. What I actually mean b1,b2,b3 etc.